# SSIS custom task is not registered for use on this computer error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, task, etl

I am setting up a new laptop (win10, old one was win7).  At my shop, we use a custom task in most of our SSIS packages.  When I open an existing package using this task I get an error:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> The task with the name "Log Start Event" and the creation name
>   "TBSM.Vision.SSIS.LoggingTask.VisionLoggingTask,
>   TBSM.Vision.SSIS.LoggingTask, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=ed92d0ee7f09d162" is not registered for use on this
>   computer. Contact Information: Vision Logging Task
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Running Visual Studio 17, version 15.9.6

At first I thought I messed up the gac, but looks like I didn't:

> C:\Windows\System32>gacutil /l TBSM.Vision.SSIS.LoggingTask Microsoft
>   (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0 Copyright
>   (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
>   TBSM.Vision.SSIS.LoggingTask, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=ed92d0ee7f09d162, processorArchitecture=MSIL
>
> Number of items = 1

What else am I missing?

## Update 1

Targeted server:

[image]

64-bit false:

[image]

DLL is in every folder it should be:

[image]

Comment: I had a very similar issue. I could edit the component when the package was in 2014 format but after I'd upgraded to 2019, I was getting that same error message.

I went to copy the DLL to the 150 DTS folder but found I didn't have a DTS folder there, just Shared.

On the off-chance, I copied the DTS folder from 120 to 150 and found that worked.

However, I'd love to know why there was no DTS folder there and whether there will be other issues with what I've done. I'm guessing I have missed a step during deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

In order to use the custom Task .DLL, you need to put the .DLL file in the `./Task` sub-directory, not the `./Pipeline` directory.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible causes:

## (1) TargetServerVersion not adequate

You are selecting a TargetServerVersion which is not relevant to the dll.

```
GoTo Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> TargetServerVersion
```

[image]

Or you have selected a TargetServerVersion that doesn't contains the task dll in the corresponding Task folders.

- SSIS 2012 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Task
- SSIS 2014 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Task
- SSIS 2016 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Task
- SSIS 2017 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Task
- SSIS 2019 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Task

***Check the first link, it contains more helpful details***

**References**

- [Error - the creation name "SSIS.ReplacementTask" is not registered](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012115473-Error-the-creation-name-SSIS-ReplacementTask-is-not-registered)
- [How to change SSIS Package Version in Visual Studio 2015 or Higher](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004811573-How-to-change-SSIS-Package-Version-in-Visual-Studio-2015-or-Higher)

## (2) Registered 32-bit dll

**It looks like you registered a 32-bit dll**

Try running the package in 32-bit mode:

```
GoTo Project properties >> Debugging >> Run64BitRuntime  = False
```

[image]

**More information at:**

- [Run an SSIS Package in 32 Bit Mode](https://support.sentryone.com/s/article/Run-an-SSIS-Package-in-32-Bit-Mode)

Comment: I posted the screenshots from my project.  it targets SQL Server 2012 and is set for 32-bit debugging.  Something else is going on I t hink

Comment: @user1443098 check that the dll is found in the following path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Task`

Comment: @user1443098 what is the visual studio version?

Comment: Running Visual Studio 17, version 15.9.6

Comment: @user1443098 what are the version of `DTSruntime.dll` used when building the custom task? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/task/creating-a-custom-task?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I don't have that dll, I have DtsRuntimeWrap in four versions, 11, 12, 13 and 14

Comment: @user1443098 i mean that when you have build the dll what are the version of DTSruntimeWrap.dll used as reference. In another way, what is the ssis version related to the DLL

Comment: @user1443098 you mentioned that `we use a custom task in most of our SSIS packages`, what is the sql server and visual studio version installed on other machine at work?

Comment: The solution does not have a reference to dtsruntimewrap at all.  the SQL Server version is 2012, Visual studio is the same.  One big diff I need to add is that the old machine is win7 and the new one win10. Tomorrow I'm going to pull the dll from the old machine and try to use it.  I'll post my findings here.

Comment: @user1443098 for sure building a custom dll require dtsruntime.dll. Last thing to try. Change targetVersion to 2017. Does it throw the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188305/discussion-between-user1443098-and-hadi).

Comment: @user1443098 last thing to try. Remove task dll from 120, 130, 140 tasks folders and from gac. Then register the dll from 110 folder and try to open package again